# How to clear a lightning:input type="file" with Locker Service enabled?

Tags: lightning, locker-service, files

I have a file input like this:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="fileInput"
            type="file" 
            label="{!v.label}" 
            name="file" 
            multiple="true" 
            accept="{!v.accept}"
            files="{!v.files}" />
```

And I want to have a button to clear the selected files after upload. The old answer is to do this:

```
component.find('fileInput').getElement().value='';
```

But, quite correctly, Locker Service won't let me go poking at the DOM inside the `lightning` namespace.

So, I might try setting `v.files` to `null`.

```
component.find('fileInput').set('v.files', null);
```

That does clear them, but when you select some more files, they don't get returned properly into `v.files`.

`v.files` is actually a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileList), which I cannot construct directly, or modify reliably. That seems to be why just zapping it with `null` breaks the file input.

It looks a lot like I'm stuck at another Lightning dead end... Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to set not null, but empty array? `component.find('fileInput').set('v.files', []);`

Comment: That's a good idea... it does seem to work. Not sure if I'm causing a potential problem for the future because I'm using an array instead of the array-like FileList, but it seems to work with a basic test.

Comment: We are looking into this. The problem is that there is no change handler on attribute of the "files" attribute of < lightning:input> to propagate changes to the <input type=“file”/> DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JF Paradis answered this above with his comment:

> We are looking into this. The problem is that there is no change
>   handler on attribute of the "files" attribute of < lightning:input> to
>   propagate changes to the  DOM element.

Comment: is there an update to this issue?

Comment: No update that I know of, but I can confirm that the workaround of using component.find('fileInput').set('v.files', []) has been working fine for me in production since I posted the question.

Comment: component.find('fileInput').set('v.files', []), this doesn't work for me. Any update on the issue?