# LWC: How to clear lighting-input[type="file"] selected file?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I think this is the same as [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189062/how-to-clear-a-lightninginput-type-file-with-locker-service-enabled), but "updated" for LWC.

I have sample codes here:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="File Select Demo" icon-name="standard:work_order_item">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium slds-clearfix">
            <lightning-input
                type="file"
                label="Select File"
                class="slds-var-m-bottom_medium"
                onchange={handleChange}
                data-name="sel"
                required
            ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button
                variant="brand"
                label="Clear File Selector"
                class="slds-float_right"
                onclick={clearSelector}
            ></lightning-button>
            <br/><br/>
            <lightning-button
                variant="brand"
                label="Check File Selector"
                class="slds-float_right"
                onclick={checkSelector}
            ></lightning-button>
            <br/>
            <template if:true={fileExist}>File exists.</template>
            <template if:false={fileExist}>File does NOT exist.</template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class FileSelectDemo extends LightningElement {
    fileExist = false;

    handleChange(event) {
        const uploaded = event.detail.files;
        if(uploaded) {
            let fileSize = uploaded[0].size;
            alert(fileSize);   // sample action of handleChange
        }
    }

    checkSelector() {
        let selInput = this.template.querySelector('[data-name="sel"]');
        if(selInput.files) {
            this.fileExist = true;
        } else {
            this.fileExist = false;
        }
    }

    clearSelector() {
        let selInput = this.template.querySelector('[data-name="sel"]');
        alert('How to clear the file selector?');
        selInput.value = '';   // <----- doesn't work
    }
}
```

My question is basically: What should I replace in the "doesn't work" line? I also tried `selInput.files = null;` or `selInput.files = [];` but doesn't work either.
Note: I need to use onchange for file selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the `lightning-input` inside an HTML `form` and use the [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) function of the form to restore form elements to default values.

```
<form>
    <lightning-input type="file"...></lightning-input>
<form>

clearSelector() {
    this.template.querySelector('form').reset();
    let selInput = this.template.querySelector('[data-name="sel"]');
    selInput.value = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saroj's answer is correct, but I just want to share a "gotcha" (at least in Chrome 103.0.5060.66). When the form is reset *and* there is/are selected file/s already, then `selInput.files` is **not** set to null, but to a FileList of length 0! It also seems that the `required` attribute for lightning-input[type="file"] checks for a falsy value of `.files`. These two imply that when you already selected a file, the message of "Completed this field" will **not** be displayed anymore, even if you reset it!

Hence, a work around would be to do the validation and set messages yourself. Here's a "fixed" code from my question:

```html
...
            <form>
            <lightning-input
                type="file"
                label="Select File"
                class="slds-var-m-bottom_medium"
                onchange={handleChange}
                data-name="sel"
                required
            ></lightning-input>
            </form>
...
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class FileSelectDemo extends LightningElement {
    fileExist = false;
    firstChange = true;   // <--- added

    handleChange(event) {
        const uploaded = event.detail.files;
        if(uploaded) {
            if(!this.firstChange) {
                event.target.setCustomValidity('');   // <--- manual clear
            } else {
                this.firstChange = false;
            }
            // sample action of handleChange
            let fileSize = uploaded[0].size;
            alert(fileSize);
        }
    }

    checkSelector() {
        let selInput = this.template.querySelector('[data-name="sel"]');
        if(selInput.files) {
            if(selInput.files.length == 0) {
                selInput.setCustomValidity('Complete this field.');   // <--- manual validation message
                this.fileExist = false;
            } else {
                selInput.setCustomValidity('');
                this.fileExist = true;
            }
        } else {
            this.fileExist = false;
        }
    }

    clearSelector() {
        this.template.querySelector('form').reset();
    }
}
```

In this case, the validation message is only displayed one the "Check File Selector" button is clicked.

Comment: Good to know that! Is it only for Chrome or all Browsers?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It seems like this is LWC problem. I modified the code above here: https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/5bCE4WtKgz73EBh0lgR9/src/app.js?p=stories. In app.js, clearSelector() (last lines), there are 2 options. In both scenarios, the file selector checkValidity() remains true after clearing.

Comment: On the other hand, file selector checkValidity() and form.reset() in plain HTML works fine in Chrome. I'll try Firefox later. Ideally in file selector, setting `value = ''` should work, because this is the suggested clearing for lightning-input[type="text"] in docs.